# Query two fields, one nested and one on the root

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write a query that that search for a string in two different fields.
One off of the root, and one as part of a nested object.

I've tried these two approaches, but neither results in matches on both fields.

**A `query_string` search off of the root**

This results in matches on `name` only

Note: If I don't specify the fields, it will search on all fields, including the two that I want.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "searchterm",
            "fields": ["name", "project.projectName"]
        }
    }
}
```

**A `query_string` search off of the nested object**

This results in matches on `project.projectName` only

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "project",
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "searchTerm",
                    "fields": [
                        "name",
                        "project.projectName"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ],
            "query": "searchTerm"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "project",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "searchTerm",
                "fields": [
                  "project.projectName"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Note** - If you want searchterm to match on both, you can replace `should` with `must`

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for a solution where I didn't have to repeat the search term, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I think you could use `include_in_parent` and make it work in one query. see the [mapping doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-nested-type.html#_mapping). `bool query` is required as nested objects are indexed as separate documents